# Sumar valores de tabla en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una consulta hacia una tabla MySQL, que me muestra un listado de productos(más abajo está el código).

En una tabla MySQL tengo el código de estos productos con el total de compras:
[image: Compras]

Y en otra tabla tengo el código de estos productos con el total de ventas por cada uno.

[image: Ventas]

Cómo puedo hacer para sumar los totales de cantidad con el mismo id de cada una de estas tablas (total de cantidad con el mismo com_det_idProducto de una y el total de cantidad con el mismo fac_det_idProducto de la otra) en el campo ARTICULO y mostrar el resultado?, miremos por ejemplo: $resultadosentradas

```
      <?php include ('conexion.php');

  $consulta = "select * from productos";

  $resultados = $conexion->query ($consulta);
 $consultaentradas = "select SUM (com_det_cantidad) from compras_detalle where com_det_idProducto = com_det_idProducto";
  $resultadosentradas = $conexion->query ($consultaentradas);


  if ($conexion->errno) {
      die ($conexion->error);
    }

      echo "<table >";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Id</td>";
        echo "<td>Nombre</td>";
        echo "<td>Stock Inicial</td>";
        echo "<td>Entradas</td>";
        echo "<td>Salidas</td>";
        echo "<td>Stock Actual</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";

      while ($fila=$resultados->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>". $fila['pro_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $fila['pro_nombre'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $fila['pro_stock_inicial'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $resultadosentradas . "</td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";


        }
        echo "</table>";

      //mysqli_close($conexion);
      $conexion->close(); 


  ?>
```

Para que el sistema me muestre algo asi:

[image: Stock]

El código SQL para crear la base de datos es:

## 01 Se crea la Base de Datos

```
create database mercury;
```

## 02 Usar BD de nombre "mercury":

```
use mercury;
```

## Usuarios internos: docentes, administrativos, comite de compras, tesorero, ordenador gasto.

```
create table usr_int(
    usr_int_id int not null auto_increment,
    usr_int_doc bigint not null,
    usr_int_usuario varchar(20) not null,
    usr_int_password varchar(20) not null,
    usr_int_nombre varchar(20) not null,
    usr_int_apellido varchar(20) not null,
    usr_int_email varchar(200) not null,
    usr_int_ciudad varchar(20) not null,
    usr_int_direccion varchar(100) not null,
    usr_int_telfijo int not null,
    usr_int_telmovil bigint not null,
    usr_int_tipo varchar(20) not null,
primary key(usr_int_id))
auto_increment=1;
```

## Usuario proveedor y empresas

```
create table usr_pro(
    usr_pro_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    usr_pro_doc bigint not null,
    usr_pro_usuario varchar(20) not null,
    usr_pro_password varchar(20) not null,
    usr_pro_nombre varchar(20) not null,
    usr_pro_apellido varchar(20) not null,
    usr_pro_email varchar(200) not null,
    usr_pro_ciudad varchar(20) not null,
    usr_pro_direccion varchar(100) not null,
    usr_pro_telfijo int not null,
    usr_pro_telmovil bigint not null,
    usr_pro_empresa varchar(40),
    usr_pro_tipo varchar(20) not null,
    usr_pro_nit int
);
```

## Principal-secundaria, principal-primaria, LaPlanta, AltoDeLaMina, LaMunioz, ElVergel.

```
create table sedes(
    sede_id int auto_increment primary key,
    sede_nombre varchar(20),
    sede_encargado int,
    foreign key (sede_encargado) references usr_int (usr_int_id)
);
```

## Estado 1- enviada 2- Aprobada 3-Rechazada

## Respuesta - Una vez aprobada o rechazada colocar aqui fecha y justificación de decisión

```
create table necesidades(
    nec_id int not null auto_increment unique,
    nec_usr_id int not null,
    nec_justi varchar(255) not null,
    nec_fech_envio date not null,
    nec_est varchar(20) not null, 
    nec_fecha_respuesta date,
    nec_est_respuesta varchar(255), 
    foreign key(nec_usr_id) references usr_int(usr_int_id),
    primary key(nec_id)
)auto_increment=1;

create table necesidades_detalles(
    id int not null auto_increment unique,
    necdet_id int,
    necdet_cant int,
    necdet_descr varchar (255),
    foreign key(necdet_id) references necesidades(nec_id)
);

create table invitaciones (
    inv_id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    inv_fech_apertura date, #es la misma fecha de publicacion de la invitación
    inv_fech_cierre date,
    inv_necesidad int,
    foreign key (inv_necesidad) references necesidades(nec_id),
    inv_anexo varchar(255) #pdf con objetivo, cantidad y descripcion
);

create table cotizaciones(
    cot_id int not null auto_increment,
    cot_fecha_envio date not null,
    cot_proveedor int,
    cot_invita_id int not null,
    cot_anex varchar(100) not null,
    cot_ValorTotal bigint,
    cot_estado varchar(30), #1. enviada 2 en estudio 3 aprobada 4 rechazada
    cot_fecha_respuesta date,
    cot_respuesta varchar(255),
    foreign key(cot_invita_id) references invitaciones(inv_id),
    foreign key (cot_proveedor) references usr_pro (usr_pro_id),
primary key(cot_id))
auto_increment=1;

create table productos (
    pro_id int auto_increment primary key,
    pro_nombre varchar (50),
    pro_stock_inicial int
);

create table compras(
    com_id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    com_fecha date,
    com_proveedor int,
    foreign key (com_proveedor) references usr_pro (usr_pro_id)
);

create table compras_detalle(
    com_det_id int auto_increment primary key,
    com_det_idCompra int,
    com_det_idProducto int,
    com_det_cantidad int,
    foreign key (com_det_idCompra) references compras(com_id),
    foreign key (com_det_idProducto) references productos(pro_id)
);

create table facturas (
    fac_id int auto_increment primary key,
    fac_fecha date,
    fac_id_cliente int,
    foreign key (fac_id_cliente) references usr_int(usr_int_id)
);

create table facturas_detalle(
    fac_det_id int auto_increment primary key,
    fac_det_idFactura int,
    fac_det_idProducto int,
    fac_det_cantidad int,
    foreign key (fac_det_idProducto) references productos(pro_id),
    foreign key (fac_det_idFactura) references facturas(fac_id)
);

create table inventario(
    inv_id int auto_increment primary key,
    inv_descripcion varchar(255),
    inv_fech_compra date,
    inv_proveedor int,
    inv_asignado_a int,
    inv_estado varchar (20),
    foreign key (inv_proveedor) references usr_pro (usr_pro_id),
    foreign key (inv_asignado_a) references usr_int (usr_int_id)
);
```

## Algunos datos de ejemplo

```
INSERT INTO usr_int (
usr_int_doc,
usr_int_usuario,
usr_int_password,   
usr_int_nombre, 
usr_int_apellido,   
usr_int_email,  
usr_int_ciudad, 
usr_int_direccion,

usr_int_telfijo,
usr_int_telmovil,   
usr_int_tipo)

values (
"9587458", 
"admin", 
"1234", 
"Juan C", 
"Rodriguez", 
"admin@gmail.com", 
"Colombia", 
"Cra 33 10-47", 
"8605478", 
"3002547874",
"Administrador"
);

INSERT INTO `mercury`.`necesidades` (`nec_id`, `nec_usr_id`, `nec_justi`, `nec_fech_envio`, `nec_est`, `nec_fecha_respuesta`, `nec_est_respuesta`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'Implementos deportivos', '2018-10-17', 'Enviada', NULL, NULL);

INSERT INTO `mercury`.`necesidades_detalles` (`id`, `necdet_id`, `necdet_cant`, `necdet_descr`) VALUES (NULL, '2', '10', 'Balones'), (NULL, '2', '15', 'Raquetas');
```

Comment: No termino de entender que es lo que quieres sumar exactamente, hablas de sumar totales de las tablas pero no veo ninguna columna totales en ellas. Disculpa las molestias pero me lo puedes aclarar? Tampoco determino bien de donde sale el 10 y el 15 en el resultado que esperas.

Comment: Pásanos el SQL de las tablas con algún registro de ejemplo y explícanos la semántica de cada campo, al usar abreviaturas no tenemos muy claro qué almacenan. Modifica tu pregunta teniendo en cuenta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Saludos

Comment: Gracias Xerif y David acabé de completar la pregunta y de incluir el SQL para que sea más clara la información.

Comment: No se entiende qué es lo que quieres sumar exactamente. Convendría que llames cada cosa por su nombre: *`quiero sumar el valor de la columnaX y de la columnaY, los datos deben agruparse por la columnaZ`*, y si acaso hay que relacionar tablas: *`la tablaA se relaciona con la tablaB mediante las columnas C de la tablaA y D de la tablaB`*  y que muestres un pequeño ejemplo de los resultados esperados. Parece que pusiste aquí todo tu sistema, incluso cosas que no sirven para entender cuál es el problema en sí. Muchas veces uno se enreda porque ni siquiera sabe verbalizar el problema.

Comment: Juan Carlos, no puedo insertar los datos del ejemplo porque salta la restricción de clave ajena, envía al menos los registros que sean necearios para calcular lo que buscas. En cualquier caso, no consigo identificar lo que pides con la estructura de la base de datos, ¿en qué tablas estaría la información que quieres procesar? Antes de programarlo tienes que ser capaz de hacerlo a mano. Inténtalo y envíanos el SQL que has probado, con una explicación de tu estrategia, a ver cómo podemos ayudarte. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hola David, te cuento que ya pude solucionar la necesidad con una consulta INNER JOIN, luego sumé los valores agrupados y listo. Ya me funciona bien.

Comment: Genial, entonces vamos a dejarlo bien rematado: edita la pregunta con el [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y [respóndete a ti mismo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) para dejarlo documentado, de forma que pueda ayudar a alguien más en el futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Señores, un saludo cordial para todos.

Bien, como les había comentado en esta pregunta, tenía varias tablas de una base de datos para gestionar un STOCK, es decir, un proceso de entrada de productos y salida de los mismos. En una tabla de registran las compras y en otra las ventas, de los productos que previamente aparecen identificados con un ID, en cada tabla se pueden repetir compras o ventas del mismo producto.

Ya logré sumar, los valores en cada una de las tablas para poder generar un STOCK, el código de la consulta SQL que empleé es el siguiente:

```
 $consulta = "SELECT pro_id AS id, pro_nombre AS producto, pro_stock_inicial AS stock,
  SUM(com_det_cantidad) AS entradas, SUM(fac_det_cantidad) AS salidas FROM productos
  LEFT JOIN compras_detalle
  ON pro_id = com_det_idProducto
  LEFT JOIN facturas_detalle
  ON pro_id = fac_det_idProducto
  GROUP BY id;";
```

El resultado que se obtiene al ejecutar el código de la consulta es el STOCK ya funcionando, el cual toma los valores de la tabla ingresos, de la tabla salidas y los presenta en una sola pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero la información sea de utilidad.